# Querying with the Query Builder

Tags: web, symfony4

I'M USING SYMFONY 4.12 I'm trying to write queries to filter my jobs(I've job table ,départements one) I first try with experience but I'm stuck in 
here is my offerController:

```
/**
 * @Route("/offres", name="offres")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param PaginatorInterface $paginator
 * @param FormFactoryInterface $formFactory
 * @return Response
 */
public function offreSearch(Request $request, PaginatorInterface $paginator ,FormFactoryInterface $formFactory):Response
{

    $datas =new OffreEmploi();
    $formFilter=$formFactory->create(OfferFilterForm::class,$datas);
    $offres = $this->repository->findSearch($datas);

    $formFilter->handleRequest($request);

    return $this->render('offre/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'OffreController',
        'offres' => $offres,
        'formulaire'   =>$formFilter->createView(),

    ]);
}
```

and this is my query in the offerRepository:

```
public function findSearch(OffreEmploi $data):?array
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');
    if ($data->getExperience() !== null) {

        $query
            ->where('o.experience > :experience')
            ->setParameter('experience', $data->getExperience());

    }
    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

when it come to enter any number IT gives the same thing it shows all the jobs stored in the database,I don't know where the problem is.
 [THE RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt1Vx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this solution:

```
public function findSearch(OffreEmploi $data):?array
{
  $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');
  if (!empty($data->getExperience())
  // ...
  }
  return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

If it doesn't work , try to dump $data->getExperience() to see its value

```
public function findSearch(OffreEmploi $data):?array
{
  $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');

  dd($data->getExperience()) ; 
}
```

**EDIT**

So try to do like this **but be sure you send the form with GET method not POST**:

```
public function offreSearch(Request $request, PaginatorInterface $paginator)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm(OfferFilterForm::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $data = $request->query->all();

    $qb = $em->getRepository(OffreEmploi::class)->findSearch($data);

    $offres = $paginator->paginate($qb, $request->query->get('page', 1), 20);

    return $this->render('offre/index.html.twig', array(
        'formulaire'   =>$form->createView(),
        'offres' => $offres,
    ));

}
```

In the formType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('experience', IntegerType::class);

    //.....

}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => null,
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ));
}


public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return null;
}
```

and in the Repository:

```
public function findSearch($data)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');
    if (!empty($data['experience'])) {
        $query
            ->where('o.experience > :experience')
            ->setParameter('experience', $data['experience']);
    }
    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

Comment: the first solution gives the same result as the first I gived in the problem it retuns all the jobs the filter doesn't work I tried the second dd($data->getExperience() it gives me .  OffreEmploiRepository.php on line 60:
null    I don't understand the problem

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-with-sql when I try with these exemple there is no problem it gives the right result

Comment: I tried but neither works I've this problem Undefined method 'findSearch'. The method name must start with either findBy, findOneBy or countBy! then I resolve it with :(qb= $this->repository->findSearch($data))  but it works like before it doesn't filter the jobs. I don't know how to fix this  mess.

Comment: Do you have create findSearch function in the OffreRepository or no ?

Comment: yes I did .thinks for help I found a solution for that even there was no difference ,no changes but it works now

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer but I just create another class witch contain all the form's field and that's it I don't know how it works because I didn't change significant things for that thinks for your help.